# Why dec 31 2010 returns 1 as week of year?

Tags: java, calendar, jodatime, week-number

For instance:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
c.setTime( sdf.parse("31/12/2010"));
out.println( c.get( Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR ) );
```

Prints 1

Same happens with Joda time.

:)

Comment: Maybe because it IS in the first week of the year 2011...?

Comment: @Ralph, es_MX, Mexico, and I would expect something different to 1.

Comment: I have extemded my answer to explain why 31. Dec belongs to the 1. Week of Year in the US. - But I don't know how it is for Mexico

Comment: Similar Question: [java get week of year for given a date](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10278410/642706)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**The definition of Week of Year is [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) dependent.**

How it is defined in US is discused in the other posts. For example in Germany ([DIN 1355-1](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_1355-1) / [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)): the first Week* of Year is the first week with 4 or more days in the new year.

**first day of week is Monday and last day of week is Sunday*

And Java’s `Calendar` pays attention to the locale. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date lastDec2010 = sdf.parse("31/12/2010");

    Calendar calUs = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);       
    calUs.setTime(lastDec2010);

    Calendar calDe = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);       
    calDe.setTime(lastDec2010);

    System.out.println( "us: " + calUs.get( Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR ) ); 
    System.out.println( "de: " + calDe.get( Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR ) );
}
```

prints:

```
us: 1
de: 52
```

**ADDED**
For the US (and I can think of that it is the same for Mexico) the 1. Week of Year is the week where the 1. January belongs to. -- So if 1. Januar is a Saturday, then the Friday before (31. Dec) belongs the same week, and in this case this day belongs to the 1. Week of Year 2011.

Answer (score 11):

> Values calculated for the WEEK_OF_YEAR
>   field range from 1 to 53. Week 1 for a
>   year is the earliest seven day period
>   starting on getFirstDayOfWeek() that
>   contains at least
>   getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() days from
>   that year. It thus depends on the
>   values of getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(),
>   getFirstDayOfWeek(), and the day of
>   the week of January 1. Weeks between
>   week 1 of one year and week 1 of the
>   following year are numbered
>   sequentially from 2 to 52 or 53 (as
>   needed).

To determine if that week is the last week of 2010 or the first of 2011 Java uses `getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek` [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()). If that method returns 7 then the first week in which all the days in the week are of the same year is week one, if it returns 1 then the first week with any days of the next year is the first week of the next year.

In this case the first of January in 2011 is on a Saturday so it is considered the first week of 2011 as long as you would like a week with one day to be considered already the first week of the next year, if you don't then do:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(7);//anything more than 1 will work in this year
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
c.setTime( sdf.parse("31/12/2010"));
System.out.println( c.get( Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR ) );
```

returns:

```
52
```

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.LocalDate.parse( 
    "31/12/2010" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( Locale.UK )  
)      
.get( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR )
```

> 52

Or, add a library, and then…

```
org.threeten.extra.YearWeek.from(     // Convert from a `LocalDate` object to a `YearWeek` object representing the entire week of that date’s week-based year.
    java.time.LocalDate.parse( "31/12/2010" , DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( Locale.UK )  
).getWeek()                           // Extract an integer number of that week of week-based-year, either 1-52 or 1-53 depending on the year.
```

> 52

## java.time

As others noted, the definition of a week varies by `Locale` in the old `java.util.Calendar` class.

That troublesome class, and its partner `java.util.Date`, have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

The [`IsoFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html) class defines a week using the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard: Week always starts on a Monday, and week # 1 holds the first Thursday of the calendar-year.

Get the current moment.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now ( zoneId );
```

Ask about the standard week-based year.

```
int week = now.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
int weekYear = now.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
```

### Standard week definition

There are many ways to define “a week” and “first week of the year”.

However, there is [one major standard definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date): the [ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). That standard defines weeks of the year, including the first week of the year.

> the week with the year's first Thursday

A standard weeks begins with Monday and ends with Sunday.

Week # 1 of a week-based year has the first Thursday of the calendar year.

The *java.time* classes support the ISO 8601 week through the [`IsoFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html) class, holding three constants that implement [`TemporalField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalField.html):

- [`WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html#WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR)
- [`WEEK_BASED_YEAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html#WEEK_BASED_YEAR)
- [`WEEK_BASED_YEARS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html#WEEK_BASED_YEARS)

Call `LocalDate::get` to access the `TemporalField`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2010-12-31" ) ;
int weekOfWeekBasedYear = ld.get( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR ) ;
int yearOfWeekBasedYear = ld.get( IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR ) ;
```

> ld.toString(): 2010-12-31
>
> weekOfWeekBasedYear: 52
>
> yearOfWeekBasedYear: 2010

## ISO 8601 string format

The ISO 8601 standard defines a textual format as well as a meaning for week-based-year values: `yyyy-Www`. For a specific date, add day-of-week numbered 1-7 for Monday-Sunday: `yyyy-Www-d`.

Construct such a string.

```
String outputWeek = String.format( "%04d" , yearOfWeekBasedYear ) + "-W" + String.format( "%02d" , weekOfWeekBasedYear ) ;
String outputDate = outputWeek + "-" + ld.getDayOfWeek().getValue() ;
```

> 2010-W52-5

## `YearWeek`

This work is much easier if you add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. Then use the [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class.

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.from( ld ) ;  // Determine ISO 8601 week of a `LocalDate`.
```

Generate the standard string.

```
String output = yw.toString() ;
```

> 2010-W52

And parse.

```
YearWeek yearWeek = YearWeek.parse( "2010-W52" ) ;
```

> yearWeek.toString(): 2010-W52

Determine a date. Pass a `java.time.DayOfWeek` enum object for day-of-week Monday-Sunday.

```
LocalDate localDate = yw.atDay( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ;
```

> localDate.toString(): 2010-12-27

I strongly recommending adding this library to your project. Then you can pass around smart objects rather than dumb ints. Doing so makes your code more self-documenting, provides [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety), and ensures valid values.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

---

For much more detail, see [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34846167/642706) on the similar Question:

- [java get week of year for given a date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10278410/642706)

…and see [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25092360/642706) on the similar Question:

- [How to calculate Date from ISO8601 week number in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25084576/642706)

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, The first week with a date of Jan 1 is week 1. 
That's why week 1 is returned for 12/31/2010.  
Try it for 12/31/2011 and you'll get 52.


**Edit: Week is locale specific, sometimes defined as Sunday - Saturday, sometimes defined as Monday - Sunday**

Comment: It most likely is looking at it from a Fiscal Year perspective which is a Monday - Sunday perspective.

Comment: Should add that "first day of the week" is locale-specific. Many countries other than the US define Monday as the first day of the week.

Comment: Not only the start of the week is locale dependent, but also how to determine the first week of a year.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the start of the week is local dependent.

In the US the Week 1 starts on the Sunday before Jan 1. In 2010 this is Dec 26. That's why Dec 31 is still week 1.

In Europe the week 1 starts on the Monday before Jan 1. In 2010 this is Dec 27. That's why also in Europe Dec 31 is still week 1.

Comment: Yes. Nevertheless if the week starts on Monday, the same principle is applied.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

As also specified in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4608695/10819573), the Week-of-Year is `Locale` dependent.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.WeekFields;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu", Locale.ROOT);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("31/12/2010", parser);
        System.out.println(date.get(WeekFields.of(Locale.US).weekOfWeekBasedYear()));
        System.out.println(date.get(WeekFields.of(Locale.GERMANY).weekOfWeekBasedYear()));
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
1
52
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.