# java get week of year for given a date

Tags: java, calendar

how can I get a week of the year given a date?
I tried the following code:

```
  Calendar sDateCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
  sDateCalendar.set(Integer.parseInt(sDateYearAAAA), Integer.parseInt(sDateMonthMM)-1, Integer.parseInt(sDateDayDD));
  System.out.format("sDateCalendar %tc\n", sDateCalendar);        
  iStartWeek = sDateCalendar.getWeekYear();
  System.out.println("iStartWeek "+iStartWeek+ " "+sDateCalendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

and i obtain:

`sDateCalendar lun apr 23 11:58:39 CEST 2012`

`iStartWeek 2012 3`

while the correct week of year is 17. Can someone help me ?

Comment: Similar Question: [Why dec 31 2010 returns 1 as week of year?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4608470/642706)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are using sDateCalendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, which is the static integer WEEK_OF_YEAR, see the source of the java.util.Calendar class:

```
public final static int WEEK_OF_YEAR = 3;
```

To get the week number, you should be using:

```
sDateCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

Comment: be careful using WEEK_OF_YEAR. It has surprises https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608470/why-dec-31-2010-returns-1-as-week-of-year

Comment: Don't play the game if you don't know the rules ;)

Comment: FYI… The `Calendar` class is now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the *java.time* classes with the adoption years ago of JSR 310.

Answer (score 30):

## tl;dr

For a year-week [defined by the ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) standard as starting on a Monday and first week contains the first Thursday of the calendar year, use the [`YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class from the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library that adds functionality to the *java.time* classes built into Java.

```
org.threeten.extra.YearWeek
.from(
    LocalDate.of( 2012 , Month.APRIL , 23 ) 
)
.toString()
```

> 2012-W17

## Definition of a Week

You need to define week-of-year.

- One common definition is that week # 1 has January 1.
- Some mean week # 1 is the first week of the year holding the first day of the week (such as Sunday in the United States).
- The standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) meaning is [that week # 1 holds the first Thursday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), and the week always begins with a Monday. A year can have 52 or 53 weeks. The first/last week can be have a week-based year different than the calendar year.

Beware that the old java.util.Calendar class has a definition of week that varies by [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

For many reasons, you should avoid the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. Instead use the new java.time framework.

## java.time

Java 8 and later comes with the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. Inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), defined by JSR 310, and extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. See [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Here is some example code to getting the ISO 8601 standard week.

Getting a date, and therefore a week, depends on the time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );
```

The [`IsoFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html) class defines a week-based year. We can ask for the:

- Week-of-year number ([`WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html#WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR))
- Year number of the week-based year ([`WEEK_BASED_YEAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html#WEEK_BASED_YEAR)).

First we get the current date-time.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now ( zoneId );
```

Interrogate that date-time object, asking about the standard week-based year.

```
int week = now.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
int weekYear = now.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "now: " + now + " is week: " + week + " of weekYear: " + weekYear );
```

> now: 2016-01-17T20:55:27.263-05:00[America/Montreal] is week: 2 of weekYear: 2016

For more info, see this similar Question: [How to calculate Date from ISO8601 week number in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25084576/642706)

### `WeekFields`

In java.time you can also call upon the [`WeekFields`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html) class, such as [`WeekFields.ISO.weekBasedYear()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#weekBasedYear--). Should have the same effect as `IsoFields` in later versions of Java 8 or later (some [bugs were fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22874374/642706) in earlier versions of Java 8).

## `YearWeek`

For standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) weeks, consider adding the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project to use the [`YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class.

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.of( 2012 , 17 ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 22):

elegant way (no need for java.util.Calendar):

```
new SimpleDateFormat("w").format(new java.util.Date())
```

Comment: This Answer ignores the crucial issue of time zone.

Answer (score 2):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.WHATEVER);
calendar.set(year, month, day);
calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

Be careful with month in Calendar, as it starts with 0, or better use Calendar.WHATEVER_MONTH