# Week of year calculation differences among Java and multi SQL RDBMS

Tags: java, sql, date, datetime, week-number

I have to do some reports and have to calc week of any date in Java and in MySQL
but they have different algorithms.

Firstly, note that by some methods, in some days in the end of some year is the first week of the next year. Examples: 2012-12-31 is the week 1 of year 2013 (I don't remember the exact year, but it like that). So I have to calc the right week year of a date

**In Java**, it bases on 2 criteria depend on locale:

- The first day of week (Sunday or Monday)
- minimal days in first week (1 or 4)

  ```
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  int javaWeek = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
  int weekYear = cal.getWeekYear();
  ```

**In MySQL**, it bases on 2 criteria depend on **mode** (0 to 7):

- The first day of week (Sunday or Monday) (this is the same in Java)
- minimal days in first week is 4 or the first week contains the first day of week

  ```
  SELECT WEEK('2012-12-12', 1);
  SELECT YEARWEEK('2012-12-12', 1);
  ```

And in MySQL, some modes will calc the week with strange result, examples, one year has week 0 with only 1 day, and other weeks have full 7 days (I think the week 1 is really the first week, and the week 0 is a pre-week or something). I will ignore these mode

**The scenario** is: I calc the week of a list of date base on my system locale (locale with setting: `getFirstDayOfWeek()==SUNDAY` and `getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek==1`) in Java and I want to calc in MySQL with the same result

But I try all 8 mode in MySQL, none matches. I fail because in MySQL there is not a mode calc week base on minimal day in first week is 1 (only some modes with 4), so I manually `setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4)` and the mode 6 in MySQL matches the result in Java

(I have to write a test, compare the result of every day in 2 years in Java and MySQL)

So ***My solution*** is, I **must fix** `setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4)`, and if `getFirstDayOfWeek()` is MONDAY, I choose mode 3 in MySQL, if  `getFirstDayOfWeek()` is SUNDAY, I choose mode 6 in MySQL. I think it is just a temporary solution and really weird.

One more problem, I am really afraid of if my system change from MySQL to other RDBMS, it will have other method and I can't handle all of them (examples in Oracle does not have WEEK function). So is there any way to calc week satisfies many RDBMS?

I have a idea is calc week in one platform (Java or MySQL) then pass the result to the other:

- If pass from Java to MySQL, I have pass the result to the query string, or build a table contains my result
- If pass from MySQL to Java, I have to write a procedure to call it from Java, and have to resolve the problem "find the way to calc week satisfies many RDBMS"

But I must calc a mass number of date, none of these satisfy me, anyone have idea to resolve my problems?

Comment: What are you planning on doing on the MySQL side?  Generally speaking, you don't want to call those functions over dates in columns, as it would invalidate the use of indices (ie, don't use for grouping for sales-by-week)...

Comment: "*Oracle does not have WEEK function)*" - Oracle *does* have the functionality to extract the week from a date. It's just not called `week()`: you need to use `to_char(some_date, 'IW')` for that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I mean when I change DB to oracle, I have to change my sql query, too.
Finally, I decide to use Calendar table (Dimension Date table), generally using in report

Answer (score 8):

## ISO 8601

While I do not have much experience with working in weeks, it seems to me the wisest approach would be to follow the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. That standard clearly [defines a week](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) and week numbers.

The standard says:

- Week starts on a **Monday**.
- Days of week are numbered `1` to `7`. Monday = 1.
- The first week contains the year's **first Thursday**.
- Weeks are numbered `01` to `53`. (No `00`.)

## WEEKOFYEAR() in MySQL

While I do not know MySQL (I'm a [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/) kind of person), I did read [this documentation on date-and-time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek).

Mode 3 of the [`WEEK( date, mode )`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function appears to comply with ISO 8601, where first day of week is Monday, weeks are numbered 1-53, has 4 or more days this year (not official definition, but another way to say 'contains first Thursday').

Furthermore, MySQL offers the [`WEEKOFYEAR( date )`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear) function specifically as shorthand for calling WEEK with mode 3. So I suggest you stick with calling WEEKOFYEAR.

## Time Zone

Time zone is crucial. The date is determined by time zone. While Montéal is enjoying the last moments before midnight on the Wednesday night of 2012-12-12, in Paris Thursday has already arrived with the date being the 13th. Same moment in the history of the Universe, but different date and time.

I assume, but do not know, that MySQL stores date-time values in [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). So I assume too that calling their week-related functions are effectively working in UTC by not applying any time zone adjustment.

I suspect this may be the root of your problem. The java.util.Calendar class *assigns the JVM’s default time zone* if you neglect to specify one. By the way, that's an important lesson: Always specify a time zone rather than rely on implicit default. So MySQL is calculating week-of-year by UTC and Calendar is calculating by some other time zone (Paris, Kolkata, whatever) then obviously results will be different.

My guess is that the solution is to either:

- Consistently do your Java work using UTC
- Apply a time zone adjustment to your date-time values in MySQL (if that is possible, I don't know).

Which of those solutions is best depends on your business policy. Some businesses may want to work by the time zone of their home office, or key supplier/customer, etc. Other businesses, especially those with concerns in various time zones choose to define everything in UTC.

I suspect the wisest choice in the long-term for most folks in this era of a shrinking world would be to always work in UTC. But I am not the person running your company.

## Joda-Time or java.time

As for the Java side of things, avoid using the java.util.Date & .Calendar classes. They are notoriously troublesome. Even Sun/Oracle has given up on them, supplanting them with the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in [Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29). That package was inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Joda-Time continues as a viable project, with java.time and Joda-Time each having their strengths and weaknesses. Both support ISO 8601 very well, and use the standard for many of their default behaviors. Both have support for week-of-year. The Joda-Time team has asked us to migrate to java.time.

Much of the java.time functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) on java.time topics.

### Example code in java.time (as of Java 8)

See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34846167/642706) to a similar Question.

The [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class represents a point on the timeline, with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), adjusted to an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_offset) (not a full time zone).

```
OffsetDateTime twelves = OffsetDateTime.of( 2012, 12, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

The [`OffsetDateTime::get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#get-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-) method lets you access any part of the value. Each part is defined as a [`TemporalField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalField.html). The `IsoFields` class provides implementations of `TemporalField` specific to the ISO-8601 calendar system. This includes the two we need:

- [IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html#WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR)
- [IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html#WEEK_BASED_YEAR)

In use…

```
int week = twelves.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
int weekYear = twelves.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
```

A time zone is an offset-from-UTC *plus* a set of rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). In some time zones the day does not begin at `00:00:00.0`. So we go through the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class (a date-only value) to let java.time determine the first moment of the day.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate twelves = LocalDate.of( 2012 , 12 , 12 );
ZonedDateTime twelvesMontreal = twelves.atStartOfDay( zoneId );
int week = twelvesMontreal.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
int weekYear = twelvesMontreal.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
```

If you are sure time-of-day and time zone is irrelevant (think twice about that!), then you can use `LocalDate` alone as it too has a [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#get-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-) method.

```
LocalDate twelves = LocalDate.of( 2012 , 12 , 12 );
int week = twelves.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
int weekYear = twelves.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
```

### Example code in Joda-Time 2.3.

The method [`getWeekOfWeekYear`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/ReadableDateTime.html#getWeekOfWeekyear()) gets the week number. The [`ISODateTimeFormat`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html) class has factory methods for producing formatters for the various week-related formats defined by ISO 8601.

```
DateTime twelves = new DateTime( 2012, 12, 12, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC );
int weekOfTwelves = twelves.getWeekOfWeekyear();
```

Create string representations. Note that you could append a call to `withZone` if you want the formatter to apply a time zone adjustment to its string generation. Otherwise, the DateTime's assigned time zone is utilized.

```
String outputWeek = ISODateTimeFormat.weekyearWeek().print(  twelves );
String outputWeekDate = ISODateTimeFormat.weekDate().print(  twelves );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "twelves: " + twelves );
System.out.println( "weekOfTwelves: " + weekOfTwelves );
System.out.println( "outputWeek: " + outputWeek );
System.out.println( "outputWeekDate: " + outputWeekDate );
```

When run.

```
twelves: 2012-12-12T00:00:00.000Z
weekOfTwelves: 50
outputWeek: 2012-W50
outputWeekDate: 2012-W50-3
```

## Portability

As for porting to database other than MySQL, I assume that sticking with the increasingly-common ISO 8601 standard will help with portability.

[Postgres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) for example [offers the functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) `isoyear`, `week`, and `isodow` (day-of-week), documented as complying with ISO 8601.