# Year-Week-Day in java.time?

Tags: java-time, iso8601, week-number

Is there support in the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes, or its extension [ThreeTen-Extra](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten-extra), for a [week dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates), specifically a Year-Week-Day such as `2009-W53-7` which is *Sunday 3 January 2010*.

As for the year-week *without* the day-of-week:

- [My Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34846167/642706) to the Question, [*java get week of year for given a date*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10278410/642706), explains using [`IsoFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html) to handle the year-week.
- The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project that extends the java.time classes offers the [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class.

But how to represent the day-of-week as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [IsoFields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html) class, which allows the week-based year and week of week-based year to be queried. There is also a dedicated formatter [ISO_WEEK_DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_WEEK_DATE).

The [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum tells you the number of the day-of-week, 1-7 for Monday to Sunday. Call [`LocalDate::getDayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getDayOfWeek--) and then [`DayOfWeek::getValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getValue--).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;
```

> 2016-12-07

```
int weekOfWeekBasedYear = ld.get( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR ) ;
int yearOfWeekBasedYear = ld.get( IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR ) ;
int dayOfWeek = ld.getDayOfWeek().getValue();
```

Use these parts to build strings in the standard [ISO 8601 week date formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates).

```
String yearWeek = yearOfWeekBasedYear + "-W" + String.format( "%02d", weekOfWeekBasedYear ) ;
```

> 2016-W49

```
String yearWeekDay = yearWeek + "-" + dayOfWeek ;
```

> 2016-W49-3

Or, let the predefined [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_WEEK_DATE) do the work.

```
String ywd = ld.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE );
```

> 2016-W49-3

That same formatter can parse such standard strings.

```
String input = "2016-W49-3" ;
LocalDate ldParsed = LocalDate.parse( input , DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE ) ;
```

> 2016-12-07

Comment: Thanks but I was asking about representing the day-of-the-week of the year-week, the `7` in `2009-W53-7`. When considered altogether, this represents the date of a single day.

Comment: The day-of-week is just `getDayOfWeek().getValue()`.