# Understanding java.util.Calendar WEEK_OF_YEAR

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

I'm trying to understand how `java.util.Calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)` works, but it seems that I'm missing some points.

```
String time = "1998-12-31"; // year month day
java.util.Calendar date = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
date.setTime((new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")).parse(time));
System.err.println("Week of year = " + date.get(java.util.Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
// Week of year = 1 Why ???
```

Why `date.get(java.util.Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)` returns 1 for the last week of the year?

Moreover, `WEEK_OF_YEAR` for `"1998-01-01"` is 1 and for `"1998-12-23"` it is 52.
Does anybody have an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: It prints `Week of year = 53` for me. Just check the code you've posted and the output you've got are from the same place.

Comment: This will be locale specific.  Have you carefully read the manual on WEEK_OF_YEAR and looked into your values for getFirstDayOfWeek and getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek?

Comment: @adashr, checked, it prints 1.

Comment: @Corbin, "First day of week = 1" and "Minimal days in the first week = 1". But I still don't understand how this may affect the last week of the year to be 1.

Comment: In some countries (e.g. USA, according to Wikipedia) the first week is the week with the 1. January. The 31. Dez '98 was a Thursday so it is in the first week of 1999

Comment: Not 100% sure on this, but my take on it:  1 Jan 1999 is a Friday.  Friday is > Sunday (1) and {Friday, Saturday} would make 2 days, thus > the 1 day minimum.  This means that 1 Jan 1999 is in week 1.  Since weeks starts on Sunday, this means that from 2 Jan 1999 to 28 Dec 1998 is week 1.  Is 1998-12-23 where it shifts to 52, or is it a random test date?  Can you confirm that only between 28 Dec and 2 Jan is week 1 (don't have access to Java at the moment).

Comment: What is your timezone and locale?

Comment: @Corbin, confirmed (between 27 Dec - 2 Jan, since my week starts on Sunday).

Comment: @yatul, timezone is `id="Europe/Moscow",offset=14400000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=78,lastRule=null`, locale is `en_US`.

Comment: @khachik Seems that's what's happening then.  I guess didn't look hard enough for the long-form explanation of it in the manual as npe just posted below basically what I was guessing Java is doing :)

Comment: This happened because of your Locale. Look at this question for description http://stackoverflow.com/q/4608470/891391

Comment: Since 1998 has actually 53 weeks it should return 53. For me it actually prints 53. http://www.epochconverter.com/date-and-time/weeknumbers-by-year.php?year=1998

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [java.util.Calendar javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

> #### First Week
>
> Calendar defines a locale-specific seven day week using two
>   parameters: the first day of the week and the minimal days in first
>   week (from 1 to 7). These numbers are taken from the locale resource
>   data when a Calendar is constructed. They may also be specified
>   explicitly through the methods for setting their values.
>
> When setting or getting the WEEK_OF_MONTH or WEEK_OF_YEAR fields,
>   Calendar must determine the first week of the month or year as a
>   reference point. The first week of a month or year is defined as the
>   earliest seven day period beginning on getFirstDayOfWeek() and
>   containing at least getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() days of that month or
>   year. Weeks numbered ..., -1, 0 precede the first week; weeks numbered
>   2, 3,... follow it. Note that the normalized numbering returned by
>   get() may be different. For example, a specific Calendar subclass may
>   designate the week before week 1 of a year as week n of the previous
>   year.

So it's locale-specific. In your case, if the week contains days from new year, it is counted as week 1 from the new year.

You can change this behavior by using [Calendar#setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek%28int%29).

Comment: thank you. Unfortunately using `setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek` does not help here (or I don't understand how to use it). If I set it to `, then I get the behavior described above. If I set it to 7, I get 52 for "1999-01-01".

Comment: Well, the week cannot be both - the last in the old year, and the first in new year. It's either one, or another.

Answer (score 8):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.LocalDate.parse( "1998-12-31" )
    .get( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR )
```

> 53

Or, add a library, and then…

```
org.threeten.extra.YearWeek.from(     // Convert from a `LocalDate` object to a `YearWeek` object representing the entire week of that date’s week-based year.
    LocalDate.parse( "1998-12-31" )   // Parse string into a `LocalDate` objects. 
).getWeek()                           // Extract an integer number of that week of week-based-year, either 1-52 or 1-53 depending on the year.
```

> 53

## Details

> I'm trying to understand how java.util.Calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) works

**Don’t!** That class is a bloody mess, and best left forgotten.

The [answer by npe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10893665/642706) is correct. In `Calendar`, the definition of a week varies by locale. A well-intentioned feature, but confusing.

### Standard week definition

There are many ways to define “a week” and “first week of the year”.

However, there is [one major standard definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date): the [ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). That standard defines [weeks of the year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates), including the [first week of the year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week).

> the week with the year's first Thursday

A standard week begins with Monday and ends with Sunday.

Week # 1 of a standard week-based-year has the first Thursday of the calendar-year.

### java.time

The *java.time* classes supplanted the troublesome legacy date-time classes. These modern classes support the ISO 8601 week through the [`IsoFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html) class, holding three constants that implement [`TemporalField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalField.html):

- [`WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html#WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR)
- [`WEEK_BASED_YEAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html#WEEK_BASED_YEAR)
- [`WEEK_BASED_YEARS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html#WEEK_BASED_YEARS)

Call [`LocalDate::get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#get-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-) to access the `TemporalField`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "1998-12-31" ) ;
int weekOfWeekBasedYear = ld.get( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR ) ;
int yearOfWeekBasedYear = ld.get( IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR ) ;
```

> ld.toString(): 1998-12-31
>
> weekOfWeekBasedYear: 53
>
> yearOfWeekBasedYear: 1998

Notice the day after, the first day of the new calendar year 1999, also is in the same week, week # 53 of week-based 1998.

```
LocalDate firstOf1999 = ld.plusDays( 1 );
int weekOfWeekBasedYear_FirstOf1999 = firstOf1999.get( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR ) ;
int yearOfWeekBasedYear_FirstOf1999 = firstOf1999.get( IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR ) ;
```

> firstOf1999.toString(): 1999-01-01
>
> weekOfWeekBasedYear_FirstOf1999: 53
>
> yearOfWeekBasedYear_FirstOf1999: 1998

## ISO 8601 string format

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines a textual format as well as a meaning for week-based-year values: `yyyy-Www`. For a specific date, add day-of-week numbered 1-7 for Monday-Sunday: `yyyy-Www-d`.

Construct such a string.

```
String outputWeek = ld.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE ) ;  // yyyy-Www
```

> 1998-W53

```
String outputDate = outputWeek + "-" + ld.getDayOfWeek().getValue() ;  // yyyy-Www-d
```

> 1998-W53-4

## `YearWeek`

This work is much easier if you add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/index.html) library to your project. Then use the [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class.

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.from( ld ) ;  // Determine ISO 8601 week of a `LocalDate`.
```

Generate the standard string.

```
String output = yw.toString() ;
```

> 1998-W53

And parse.

```
YearWeek yearWeek = YearWeek.parse( "1998-W53" ) ;
```

> yearWeek.toString(): 1998-W53

Determine a date. Pass a `java.time.DayOfWeek` enum object for day-of-week Monday-Sunday.

```
LocalDate localDate = yw.atDay( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ;
```

> localDate.toString(): 1998-12-28

I strongly recommending adding this library to your project. Then you can pass around smart objects rather than dumb ints. Doing so makes your code more self-documenting, provides [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety), and ensures valid values.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

---

## Joda-Time

**UPDATE:** The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. This section left intact as history.

The excellent Joda-Time framework uses ISO 8601 for its defaults. Its classes include this week-of-year information. Joda-Time is a popular replacement for the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date & java.util.Calendar classes bundled with Java.

### Example Code

Here is some example code to get first moment of the first day of the first week of the year of the current date-time.

Note the call to `withTimeAtStartOfDay` to get the first moment of the day.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );

DateTime now = new DateTime( timeZone );
DateTime firstWeekStart = now.withWeekOfWeekyear(1).withDayOfWeek(1).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
DateTime firstWeekStop = firstWeekStart.plusWeeks( 1 );
Interval firstWeek = new Interval( firstWeekStart, firstWeekStop );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "now: " + now );
System.out.println( "firstWeekStart: " + firstWeekStart );
System.out.println( "firstWeekStop: " + firstWeekStop );
System.out.println( "firstWeek: " + firstWeek );
```

When run…

```
now: 2014-02-07T12:49:33.623+01:00
firstWeekStart: 2013-12-30T00:00:00.000+01:00
firstWeekStop: 2014-01-06T00:00:00.000+01:00
firstWeek: 2013-12-30T00:00:00.000+01:00/2014-01-06T00:00:00.000+01:00
```

Comment: Maybe update this with `java.time`?

Comment: @cricket_007 Ask, and ye shall receive.