# Build calendar and disable specific days

Tags: android, calendar

I have been trying so many library's and different codes to be able to achieve building custom calendar and be able to disable all week days except specific days.

im getting arraylist in API with list of days that are available to delivery,
so the calendar need to display the whole month disabled except the days that im getting from API for example: he can select every Friday and Saturday only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this library [Material Date Time Picker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker#additional-options), here you can set an option to show specific dates, For Example:

```
datePicker.setDisabledDays(Calendar[] days)
```

And an pass array of Calendar as a parameter which contains all the selectable date.[Get all Fridays in a date Range in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527998/get-all-fridays-in-a-date-range-in-java)

Comment: link is not working please update and could you see the array of parameters to show an example? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can always build your own calendar
here is a link to develop your own calendar in 7 setps:
https://medium.com/@avi_kr16/creating-a-simple-android-calendar-in-7-steps-fa18a7945350

hope it helps

Comment: and how do u disable those days

Comment: In step 4. Create each days and add days in weeks. you can check if this day is valid if no disable it by not attaching an onClickListener, change color etc...