# How can I enable only specific days in datepicker Android?

Tags: java, android

Basically I am making an appointment application. So I am showing days in a list, when user select any day then the datepicker pops up and shows only respective day date enabled 3,4 weeks. For example, if I select Monday then all the Mondays of this month enabled. 7, 14, 21, 28

Comment: you need to create datepicker of your own or find some library that allowed to strict date and apply date range

Comment: You may have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35599203/disable-specific-dates-of-day-in-android-date-picker)

Comment: you have to visit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54440903/datepicker-only-select-mondays

Answer (score 0):

when you describe onPickerListener
something like this

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        setInitialDateTime();
    }
};
```

describe and process your special days inside onDateSet
imho

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: try another way. i think it is easier https://learntodroid.com/how-to-disable-dates-in-a-datepicker-for-android/

Comment: or even here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53454711/how-do-you-disable-certain-days-on-a-datepicker-android

Comment: Thank you brother

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MaterialDateTimeOPicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker)

Pass values in this list that are the acceptable dates for the picker.

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog datePicker = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
  MainActivity.this,
  now.get(Calendar.YEAR), // Initial year selection
  now.get(Calendar.MONTH), // Initial month selection
  now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) // Inital day selection
);

 datePicker.setSelectableDays(Calendar[] days)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, I posted a question asking *How can I enable only specific dates in DatePicker Android. Like whenever user click on specific day only those respective dates will available in DatePicker?*. I have solved it, which I will share here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here are the screenshots that when user click on Monday then DatePicker pops up and enable only Mondays from that day.

`code`

```
@Override    
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Day day = days.get(position);
                    switch (day.getDay()){
                        case "Monday":
                            appDay = 2;
                            break;
                        case "Tuesday":
                            appDay = 3;
                            break;
                        case "Wednesday":
                            appDay = 4;
                            break;
                        case "Thursday":
                            appDay = 5;
                            break;
                        case "Friday":
                            appDay = 6;
                            break;
                        case "Saturday":
                            appDay = 7;
                            break;
                        case "Sunday":
                            appDay = 1;
                            break;
                        default:
                            appDay = 0;
                            break;
                    }
                    datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(DayListFragment.this,Year, Month, Day);
                    datePickerDialog.setThemeDark(false);
                    datePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Appointment Date");
                    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int today = calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                    if ( appDay == today)
                    {
                        int update = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < calendars.length; i++)
                        {
                            final Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                            calendar2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                            calendar2.add(Calendar.DATE, update);
                            calendars[i] = calendar2;
                            update += 7;
                        }
                    }
                    else if ( appDay > today)
                    {
                        int for1 = appDay - today;
                        for (int i = 0; i < calendars.length; i++)
                        {
                            final Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                            calendar2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                            calendar2.add(Calendar.DATE, for1);
                            calendars[i] = calendar2;
                            for1 += 7;
                        }
                    }
                    else if ( appDay < today)
                    {
                        int for2 = (7-today)+appDay;
                        for (int i = 0; i < calendars.length; i++)
                        {
                            final Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                            calendar2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                            calendar2.add(Calendar.DATE, for2);
                            calendars[i] = calendar2;
                            for2 += 7;
                        }
                    }
                    datePickerDialog.setSelectableDays(calendars);
                    datePickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(),"DatePickerDialog");
                }
```

Comment: You could have simplified this snippet to ```datePickerDialog.setSelectableDays(calendars)```, the rest of the code doesn't answer the question. The problem is that native ```DatePickerDialog``` doesn't have such method. Probably, you use some library and you should have mentioned this.

Comment: After searching several days, able to find this comment. Helped a lot. If the developer(s) could incorporate examples for each of the feature, it help a lot for novice persons. Thank you.