# Java number of week is different than Python and PHP

Tags: java, php, python

I have some calculations being done based on the current week of the year. On this current date (4/26/2016), both Python and PHP return the current week as being the 17th week in the year. Java, however, returns 18. How do I ensure that Java returns the same as Python and php?

```
// Java
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR); // Returns 18

 // Python
 datetime.datetime.now().isocalendar()[1] // Returns 17

// php

$current_date = new DateTime('now');
$current_date->format("W") // Returns 17
```

Comment: April 26, 2016 *is* the 18th week of the year from my count - are the other ones zero based?

Comment: I get 17 in all languages you have posted. Are you running all these commands on the same machine? Also what time zone are you in?

Comment: @Chris, Python and php are on the same machine. The Java code is actually being run on my Android device. I tried setting the locale as such:         Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")); and still get 18.

Comment: @stdunbar ISO weeks are a bit weird because this year started on a Friday. The first week of a year is considered to be the week with the first Thursday in it, making this the 17th week of the ISO year, because the first 3 days of the year are considered the last week of 2015.

Comment: You have your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893443/understanding-java-util-calendar-week-of-year

Comment: Thanks @Chris - didn't know that but I did wonder how a split week works.  Now I know.

Comment: @KerbKerb, maybe I'm not understanding correctly but changing the minimal days in first week should adjust the week correctly? I've tried setting it from 1-7 and it still returns 18. I've also tried setting the locale to US, where I am located.

Comment: Well, changing the minimal days changes it to the correct week number on my machine, but my Android device still returns 18 no matter what the minimal days is set to.

Comment: Have you set first day of week to Monday?

Comment: @AniaG, yes I did what you described below. It works on my machine but still returns 18 on Android. The only thing that seems to be working on Android at the moment is using Local.UK instead of Locale.US. For the time being, it works but I don't understand why Locale.US is always return 18 on Android.

Comment: The .Calendar and .Date classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time framework. The java.time classes define a week according to the ISO 8601 standard. [Back-ported to Java 6 & 7](http://www.threeten.org/) and [adapted to Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Answer (score -1):

To implement ISO 8601 first week (Python's isocalendar uses it) you need to set minimal days in first week to 4 and first day of week to Monday (which is iso first day of week). 
This is enough to satisfy iso definition of first week, as

> the week with the year's first Thursday in it.

So all you have to do is:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
now.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4); 
now.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);// Returns 17
```

Comment: The `minimalDaysInFirstWeek` is 4 by default in Java.

Comment: According to documentation, it's locale-specific. Without setting it explicitly, I get 1, not 4.

Comment: Indeed you are right. From the nasty resource file that sets the default it looks like it might be 4 by default in the UK but 1 in the US.