# Is there any DateTime library which supports quarter of the year and week of the year Java?

Tags: java, datetime

I am currently using jodaTime [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class for my Java project. But it does not have support for **quarter of the year** and **week of the year**.

Is there any Java library which can be used for that purpose?

Comment: Quarter is trivial, you can implement that easily yourself. For week of the year, java.util.Calendar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893443/understanding-java-util-calendar-week-of-year

Comment: @ManoDestra what is the week format it supports? i.e. mon-sun or sun-sat ?

Comment: It defaults to the local locale, but you can set the locale yourself explicitly, of course. See the link I posted for further info.

Comment: [Asked and answered](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48724/1255) on sister site, *Software Recommendations Stack Exchange*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In java 8 [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) supports quarters using `q` format and week of the year using `w`:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("qqq w");
String text = date.format(formatter);
```

Results in third quarter and 31st week of the year for todays date (July 25th):

```
"Q3 31"
```

Comment: it supports sun-sat or mon-sun?

Comment: I didn't understand what is 'qqq' in your code?

Comment: It is a formatting symbol for quarter in `Q3` format, if you use `qq` you will get `03` and single `q` will get you `3` (see javadocs).

Answer (score 1):

## ThreeTen-Extra

> Is there any Java library which can be used for that purpose?

Yes.

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project has classes for:

- [`Quarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Quarter.html)
  An enum representing the 4 quarters of the year - `Q1`, `Q2`, `Q3`, and `Q4`. These are defined as January–March, April–June, July–September, and October–December.
- [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html)
  A year-quarter in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) calendar system, such as `2007-Q2`.
- [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html)
  A year-week in the [ISO week date system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) such as `2015-W13`.

No need to reinvent the wheel with your own. These classes also provide extra functionality such as math with `plus` and `minus` methods.

ThreeTen-Extra extends the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later, defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And ThreeTen-Extra is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.

---

Both Joda-Time and java.time are led by the same man, [Stephen Colbourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) team advises migration to java.time. Joda-Time is still actively supported for maintenance but any major new work will be put into java.time and ThreeTen-Extra instead of Joda-Time.

Comment: I should try this :)