# android: 08/29 and 08/30 different week_of_year?

Tags: java, android, calendar, week-number

if i try to get the actual week of year like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
actualWeek = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

i get 35 for actualWeek

but for

```
cal.set(2013, 7, 30);
int week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

i get 40

and 42 for

```
cal.set(2013, 8, 18);
int week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

what is wrong with my calendar? it should be 35 for 8/29 and 8/30 and 38 for 9/18

Comment: What sort of week-numbering are you expecting? There are *lots* of different types of week-numbering available.

Comment: Could it be due to calendar month starts from ZERO?http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH

Comment: @Nambari thats why i use 2013, 7, 30 for 2013/08/30

Comment: @JonSkeet i'm expecting the number of the week of the year  starting at 1 like i get it in the first example (35 for the actual week). i don't think that i can get different types when i use the same method.

Comment: @NathanMaier: Sure, it should give consistent results - but it would really help if you'd explain where you got the numbers you were expecting. "The number of the week of the year" is not one well-defined concept.

Comment: I just ran your example and got 35 for both top 2 cases.

Comment: I looked at your profile and it seems like you are posting from Germany? Week of the year is local and it is different in USA and Germany. Search issue on SOF and you will find similar posts.

Comment: I don't know solution but using `GregorianCalendar()` might be solution, give it a try

Comment: @JonSkeet i don't know how to define it better. i mean that the week from 2013/1/1 to 1/5 was week 1, the week from 1/6 to 1/12 was week 2 and the week from 12/29 to 12/31 will be week 52. and next year it starts at 1 again.

Comment: @GokhanArik whats the difference, except that week starts at monday in germany and at sunday in us? monday/sunday makes no difference because 08/29 and 08/30 are thursday and friday

Comment: I found that but it is about end of the year. I am not sure if it applies to you. As I said earlier try to use Gregorian Calendar. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4608695/1106598

Comment: @GokhanArik using GregorianCalendar doesn't change anything

Comment: @GokhanArik that doesn't really apply to my problem because it's only about the last and first week of a year

Comment: i have no idea why but after i updated android studio and downloaded the sdk for api 18 it works!