# Calendar in java get year issue

Tags: java

I have this code :

```
Calendar sDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY); 
int CurrentWeek = sDateCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR); 
int Year = sDateCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

when the date is ,for example, 29/12/2014

CurrentWeek variable will be 1 because the first week in 2015 is from : December 29, 2014 to : January 4, 2015
BUT the Year variable will have 2014 and not 2015

Can you please help me resolving this issue ?

Comment: Well, it's clear that 29/12/2014 is *not* in 2015.  So you must instead want `WEEK_OF_YEAR` to produce "53".  Is that right?

Comment: If the date belongs to 2014, why would you want the 'year' to be 2015?

Comment: When I run this code on my machine `CurrentWeek` is `52`. Are you sure about the result you're describing?

Comment: Take care: there are different definitions as to when a week extending over 31/12+1/1 belongs to the closing year or already to the next. Locale!

Comment: Bob, the fact that (according to Germany's DIN definition) the week already belongs to 2015 as its first week doesn't make 29/12/2014 a day of 2015. And a week split between years is either 5x in one year or 1 in the next.

Comment: 100 % laune but is there any function in java that returns 2015 instead of 2014

Comment: You'll have to look at the Thursday of the week to which the "current" day (29/12) belongs and take its year. ("Die Kalenderwoche 1 eines Jahres ist diejenige, die den ersten Donnerstag enthält.") You can get the day of the week of the current day and add or subtract to Thursday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I wrote this method and I guess its the answer of my question :

```
public static void yearCalc() {
    Calendar sDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
    int currentWeek = sDateCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    int currentMonth = sDateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int Year = sDateCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    if (currentWeek == 1 & currentMonth == 11) {
        Year = Year + 1;
    }

    sDateCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Year);
    sDateCalendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, currentWeek);

    sDateCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 2);

    String a = sDateCalendar.getTime().toString();

    System.out.println(a);

    sDateCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Year);
    sDateCalendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, currentWeek);

    sDateCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 8);
    String b = sDateCalendar.getTime().toString();

    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static int getYearOfWeek(int year, int month, int day ){
    Calendar cc = new GregorianCalendar( year, month, day );
    int dow = cc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); 
    if( dow == 1 ) dow = 8;   // adjust Sunday
    int diff = Calendar.THURSDAY - dow;
    Calendar thc = new GregorianCalendar( year, month, day + diff );
    return thc.get(Calendar.YEAR);
}
```

Comment: I used this function with 2 examples : first one with 29/12/2014 and the result was 2015 which is 100% correct 
                                       2nd example with 28/12/2014 and the result was also 2015 which is wrong

Comment: Ah, drat! Calendar has SUNDAY == 1, which does not agree with German (AT, CH,...) standards.

Comment: So any other suggestions please ? 
Tx for the help laune

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608470/why-dec-31-2010-returns-1-as-week-of-year) in Java, `WEEK_OF_YEAR` is local dependent; there are different rules from country to country.

Another issue you may experience: which is the first day of week? (Sunday? or Monday?), so combine your selected locale with `sDateCalendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);` (or SUNDAY).

There is a method to define when a week starts by calling sDateCalendar.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(7); so the first week will be the first full (7 days) week of the year.

Comment: Calendar.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY) has Monday the first day of week no ?

Comment: use this to check: System.out.printf("First day of week: %d%n", sDateCalendar.getFirstDayOfWeek()); Sunday is 1, Monday is 2 .. Saturday is 7