# How to get the YEAR for week of year for a date?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I know that `Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR` could been used to obtain the "week of year" for a given date, but how do I get the corresponding YEAR?.

I know that the definition of  [Week of Year is dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4608695/280244) on [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html). And I am mostly interested in a DIN 1355-1 / [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) / German solution *(but I do not want to make it a fix implementation)*.

So it could happen that the 1 January belongs to:

- the first week of year (1) of the new year: for example 2015-01-01 is in week of year 1 of 2015
- the last week of year (53) of the year before: for example 2016-01-01 is in week of year 53 of year **2015**

My question is how to get this year?*

```
Date date =
Calender calendar = new GregorianCalendar(Locale.GERMAN)
calendar.setTime(date);

int weekOfYear = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
int year       = ????                                             <------------

System.out.println(date + " is in " + weekOfYear + " of " + year);
```

** the solution is not: `date.getYear`, `date.getFirstDayOfWeek.getYear` or `date.getLastDayOfWeek.getYear`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Java 8 or later?***

Refer to [Basil Bourque's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34971333/5698098) to **use Java's [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)** API.

Otherwise (think twice!) see my original answer to use the obsolete Java API as asked in this question.

---

***Pre Java 8?***

`calendar.getWeekYear();` returns `2015` for your given example.

See API documentation for [GregorianCalendar#getWeekYear()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#getWeekYear--) as well as [week year](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_year).

***For reference***

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(Locale.GERMAN);
calendar.set(2016, Calendar.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0, 0);
Date date = calendar.getTime();

int weekOfYear = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
int year       = calendar.getWeekYear();

System.out.println(date + " is in " + weekOfYear + " of " + year);
```

returns

```
Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 2016 is in 53 of 2015
```

Answer (score 3):

## java.time

You should be using the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. Avoid the old and notoriously troublesome java.util.Date/.Calendar classes.

These new java.time classes include [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) for date-only value without time-of-day or time zone. Note that you must specify a time zone to determine ‘today’ as the date is not simultaneously the same around the world.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now ( zoneId );
```

The [`IsoFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html) class provides info according to the ISO 8601 standard including the week-of-year for a week-based year.

```
int calendarYear = now.getYear();
int weekNumber = now.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
int weekYear = now.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR );  // Answer to Question
```

Near the beginning/ending of a year, the week-based-year may be ±1 different than the calendar-year. For example, notice the difference between the Gregorian and ISO 8601 calendars for the end of 2015: Weeks 52 & 1 become 52 & 53.

[image]

[image]