# Get the week of year, with sunday as the first day of the week using java calendar

Tags: java, calendar

I'm trying to generate some code for our financial department, and they require a field that will give them the current week of the year, but based off of Sunday being the first day of the week. So for instance 01-25-16 (MM-dd-yyyy) would be week 4. However when I try it using `java.util.Calendar` and `calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek` to Sunday, it tells me that this is week 5 because it seems to be counting from the end of December to the 3rd of January as week 1.

Here is the code I've written so far:

```
private static int getWeekOfYearBySunday(DateTime dt){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(dt.getMillis());
    calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);

    return calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
}
```

This returns a week number of 5, even though it should be 4 if basing the start of the week on Sunday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change `minimalDaysInFirstWeek`, see [Calendar#setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(int)):

> Sets what the minimal days required in the first week of the year are; For example, if the first week is defined as one that contains the first day of the first month of a year, call this method with value 1. If it must be a full week, use value 7.

See also [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html):

> For example, January 1, 1998 is a Thursday. If `getFirstDayOfWeek()` is `MONDAY` and `getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()` is 4 (ISO 8601 standard compatible setting), then week 1 of 1998 starts on December 29, 1997, and ends on January 4, 1998. The week year is 1998 for the last three days of calendar year 1997. If, however, `getFirstDayOfWeek()` is `SUNDAY`, then week 1 of 1998 starts on January 4, 1998, and ends on January 10, 1998; the first three days of 1998 then are part of week 53 of 1997 and their week year is 1997.

But if you code for your *financial department*, you should rather create your calendar with the right [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) instead of changing some properties, see [Calendar#getInstance(Locale)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance(java.util.Locale)):

> Gets a calendar using the default time zone and specified locale. The `Calendar` returned is based on the current time in the default time zone with the given locale.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of week of year is locale dependent. See this related question for more information. [Why dec 31 2010 returns 1 as week of year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608470/why-dec-31-2010-returns-1-as-week-of-year).