# Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR is Different in My 2 Android Phone

Tags: java, android, calendar

I have this code

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

When you get the `c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)` it produce different week number

example `c.set(2016, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);`

one android phone produce `c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)` = 1
and the other one is `c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)` = 53

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to count the weeks-of-year.
This will probably help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4608695

Comment: tried that already, Its the same, if I follow that the result would be like this in one phone, US = 1 DE = 52, the other is US = 52, DE = 53