# Java WEEK_OF_YEAR

Tags: java, date

I implemented the following method:

```
    private int getWeek(String datum){

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = format.parse(datum);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone( "Europe/Berlin" ));
    calendar.setTime(date);

    int week = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    return week;
}
```

But when I call the method with

```
getWeek("01.01.2017")
```

it returns 52. But it should be 1.
Where is my mistake?

When i call the method with

> ```
> getWeek("01.01.2016")
> ```

it returns 53.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a better one IIRC, but https://stackoverflow.com/q/4608470/5647260

Answer (score 0):

you have lost set the `TimeZone` in [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone-java.util.TimeZone-), for example:

```
private int getWeek(String datum) {
    TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin");
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

    //     v--- set the timezone here 
    format.setTimeZone(zone);

    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = format.parse(datum);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(zone);
    calendar.setTime(date);

    int week = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    return week;
}
```

Comment: I used your whole method to test it, it also returns 52.

Comment: @sHarivaRi are you sure? have you re-compiled your classes again?

Comment: Yes, but your code is correct, because the 01.01.2017 is really the 52. week of year in Germany.

Comment: @sHarivaRi ..., I'm from China. both `01.01.2016` and `01.01.2017` output  are `1`  in my computer.

Comment: Yeah, i guess you use another system than germany to count your week of year.

Comment: @sHarivaRi I think it is irrelevant. since you use the same `TimeZone`. and the output should both are `1` too in your machine. please make sure your source code / project was rebuild.

Comment: Read the duplicate. It does not depend on `TimeZone`, it depends on `Locale`

Answer (score 0):

Damnit.. that was a huge brain failure.
52 is the correct answer for the input.

in Germany the first Week of Year is the first week with 4 or more days in the new year.

Sorry.

Comment: It is not just Germany, it is actually an ISO standard (ISO-8601), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date